# VBA excel counter with maximum

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing to you today as I have an issue with counting the value on a given year of the quantities I have ordered.

This is an example of what I have :

[image]

I want to sum the values in the column slidy year per line with a maximum of 12 Qx/201x that are the last months on my line. I have put a "1" below every column that had a "Qx/201x" but I only want to keep the 12 last and to sum the values according to that.

Would you have an easy idea with VBA on how I could get that done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
 Function SumIfColMatch(ByVal matchRow As Integer, ByVal matchString As String, ByVal sumRange As Range, ByVal maxToCount As Integer)
    Dim dblTotal As Double
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim sumCount As Integer

    sumCount = 0

    For lngCounter = sumRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(matchRow, lngCounter).Value Like matchString Then
            dblTotal = dblTotal + sumRange(lngCounter).Value
            sumCount = sumCount + 1
            If sumCount >= maxToCount Then Exit For
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    SumIfColMatch = dblTotal

End Function
```

> ```
> In the formula cell use something like this
>
>     =SumIfColMatch(1,"Q*/201*",A3:DL3,12)
> ```

It works for me see attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: I don't want to sum everything but just the cells under the columns Q*/201* per line and that would be my slidy year. I have tried your function but it doesn't work the way I need to. Would you have any other idea ? Thank you in advance